# WordPress - function triggered after post request generate an error 500

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

When I send a post request to my WordPress Rest API in order to create a post, the post is well created ; but if I add an action to trigger a function after this post request, I get an error 500.

The error occurs whatever the hook I use : `rest_insert_{$this->post_type}`, `save_post` or `transition_post_status`...

The problem occurs even if I send my request trough Postman.

How can I solve this error and trigger my function after my post request?

**UPDATE**

Here is my code to send the request using Nuxt (vuej):

```
async send() {
  if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
    let payload = {};
    payload = {
      first_name: this.first_name,
      last_name: this.last_name,
      budget: this.budget,
      email: this.email,
      message: this.message
    };
    try {
      await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: this.baseUrl,
        data: {
          title: this.first_name + " " + this.last_name,
          fields: payload,
          status: "private"
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  } else {
    window.scrollTo(0, 400);
  }
}
```

And my WP functions.php

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'custom_send_admin_email', 10, 3 );
function custom_send_admin_email( $post_id, $post, $update  ) {
    // Only want to set if this is a new post!
    if ( $update ){
        return;
    }

    // Only set for post_type = post!
    if ( 'message' !== $post->post_type ) {
        return;
    }
        // Consider sending an email here.
        $to = 'adebord@agencedebord.com';
        $subject = 'The subject';
        $body = 'Nom : ' . $post['acf']['nom'];
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the [error log](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) yet? If so, what does it say? Also, where's your code?

Comment: I have updated my post to provide further informations.